# Where to find source code for android `dx` tool, version 1.16?

Tags: android, dx

googling "dx source code" gives [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/a9ac3a9d1f8de71bcdc39d1f4827c04a952a0c29/dx/src/com/android/dx/Version.java?autodive=0) but it's version 1.7.

By going up the path, I can find later versions of the entire platform (it seems), but not clear to me which one contains which versions of dx. I could trial-and-error to find it, but there'a got to be a better way!

I found version 1.16 [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.rover12421.android/dx/1.16/source-code/com/android/dx/Version.java) at jar-download.com  but I don't know if it's legit (I could theoretically hand-check it all...). It doesn't seem related to google.  EDIT This turned out to be just the class files, no java source.

Comment: Maybe this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/a9ac3a9d1f8de71bcdc39d1f4827c04a952a0c29/dx

Comment: @MayRestinPeace Thanks, but that's the version in my first link, 1.7...

Comment: I took your link and replaced the specific commit sha with "master" to see the most up to date source, which happens to be 1.16.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/dx/src/com/android/dx/Version.java?autodive=0

Comment: in the code there is a line at the bottom
"public static final String VERSION = "1.7";"

Comment: Thank you @JesusFreke! I never would have thought of that (though I know about git hashes and the "master" branch name) This google git web interface doesn't have much in the way of UI or docs. I'm curious: how did you know about it? Or was it a guess you tried? PS could you make it an answer, so I can select it please? I think it makes it easier for later readers, rather than going through all the comments.

Comment: @hatirlatici ? That's why I said it was version 1.7... BTW perhaps surprisingly, 1.16 > 1.7 in this numbering scheme.